# how to delete blob storage container azure NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, blob, containers

I am trying to delete a whole blob storage container with [Azure-storage-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node)

But I cannot seem to find anywhere how to do this. There is a lot of information about how to do this for blobs. But in my case I need to delete the whole container. 
I am working on a NodeJS server. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you would want to call is [`deleteContainer`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L853) or [`deleteContainerIfExists`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L903). This would delete an entire container.

```
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService();
blobSvc.deleteContainerIfExists('mycontainer', function(error, result, response){
    if(!error){
      console.log('container deleted!')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I couldn't find anywhere how to do this. But still it looks so simple :)